# How to print the value stored in an char[] or string in the program itself

Tags: c++, c, macros, concatenation, string-concatenation

Have any one tried anything like this?

Is it possible to print the value of a string or integer on the program itself? Say for example - I have written 2 tests for a program I am trying to call all the tests functions by looping over in a for loop.

A small sample example

```
#define MAX_TESTS 10


for(test_idx = 0; test_idx<MAX_TESTS; ++test_idx)
{
   test_##test_idx();

  //Here the output will be more like "test_test_idx();"
  //But I am looking for something like 
  //"test_0();"
  //"test_1();"
  //"test_2();"
    .
    .
    .
  //"test_9();"
}
```

Is there a way to do it in C?

---

Complete Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Macros 
#define MAX_TEST 2   
#define _MYCAT(a,b) a##b()

void test_0() 
{
  printf("Test 0\n");
}

void test_1()
{
  printf("Test 1 \n");
}

int main()
{
   printf("Max Product Testing \n");

   for (int test_idx=0; test_idx<MAX_TEST; ++test_idx)
   {
      /* Try - 1
      char buffer[50];
      int n = sprintf(buffer, "test_%d", test_idx);
      printf("%s %d \n", buffer, n);
     */

     //Try - 2
     //_MYCAT(test_, test_idx);
   }
   return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: Names of functions aren't available in runtime except for debugging information. `for` loop isn't available in preprocessor. Then... how about creating an array containing pointers to functions and use it?

Comment: "for (int test_idx=0; test_idx<MAX_TEST; ++test_idx)", "for" loop initial declarations are only available in C99 mode.

Comment: @Mirakurun How is that related to what the OP wants ?

Comment: Defining `_MYCAT` in C invokes *undefined behavior* because identifiers that begin with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers).

Comment: @Mirakurun: Forgot to mention, I compiled that code in main.cpp. Most people I work with only know C and I prefer making the code look cleaner like loop initial declaration etc. So I write C code in .cpp files for writing unit tests that will never be ported across or ever used again.

Comment: @howtechstuffworks Why not use `.c` files if you are writing C, not C++?

Comment: @MikeCAT: No particular reason -  I switch between C and C++ often, so didnt notice the difference until someone pointed out.

Comment: @ameyCU it is related to his code, and a little comment to improve his code isn't forbidden. It was only logical that he uses .c file and it wouldn't compile successful on it.

Comment: @MikeCAT: I thought about that -  thats the first thing that came to my mind. Just trying this out for fun. One more idea would be - autogenerate an .c file - that has the "for loop" in a function foo() in autogenerate.c/.h and call the function from main() in main.c and place the test_0() and test_1() test.c/.h - not sure if it is feasible.

Comment: @kfsone: I dont see a reason why you should downvote -  as I mentioned before I am just trying it out for fun in learning either one of the language. Its just stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The closet you can get in **C++** is to keep a map of function names to functions as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void test_0() 
{
  printf("Test 0\n");
}

void test_1()
{
  printf("Test 1 \n");
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, function<void()>> func_map;
    func_map["test_0"] = test_0;
    func_map["test_1"] = test_1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        func_map.at("test_" + to_string(i))();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of function pointers and call each one in a loop.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test_0()
{
    printf("Test 0\n");
}

void test_1()
{
    printf("Test 1\n");
}

void test_2()
{
    printf("Test 2\n");
}

int main()
{
    void(*a)() = test_0;
    void(*b)() = test_1;
    void(*c)() = test_2;

    const int SIZE = 3;
    void(*arr[SIZE])() = {
        { a }, { b }, { c }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        arr[i]();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test 0
Test 1
Test 2
```